# ZfcTwig is not loading config and fails in bootstrap

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Hi I am relatively new to ZF2 so this might be a very simple mistake I am making.

**Problem**

When loading the `ZfcTwig` module I get an exception that

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Twig_Environment' in /www/ZendFramework2/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 555

This Exception is thrown in the `onBootstrap` function of `ZfcTwig\Module.php`:

```
<?php
class Module implements
  BootstrapListenerInterface,
  ConfigProviderInterface
{
  public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
  { 
    /** @var \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e*/
    $application    = $e->getApplication();
    $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
    $environment    = $serviceManager->get('Twig_Environment'); // throws the exception
    //...
  }
  public function getConfig(){ return [/*...*/]; } // never called
}
```

What I don't get is why is bootstrap called before configuration was loaded. The `'Twig_Environment'` service is configured in the config of the ZfcTwig module, but that config has not been loaded, when onBootstrap is called.

## Setup

ZF2 loader via `ZF2_PATH` environment variable. Not using the composer autoloader.

in `application.config.php` I set an additional modules path `'/global/vendor'` to my sytem wide repository of reusable modules. I am not using a project local vendor folder.

From `'/global/vendor/ZfcTwig'` I am loading the module `ZfcTwig` ([link](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcTwig)) to get Twig template engine support in ZF2.

Since this relies on the twig library I put the twig lib into 
`'/global/vendor/twig'`

To enable autoloading for the ZfcTwig module and the twig library classes I changed Module.php of ZfcTwig by implementing the `AutoloaderProviderInterface` and adding configs for both twig and ZfcTwig.

```
<?php
class Module implements
    BootstrapListenerInterface,
    AutoloaderProviderInterface,
    ConfigProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Autoloading the twig library and this modules classes
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        $pathToTwigLib = dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))) . '/twig/twig/lib/Twig';
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__,
                ),
                'prefixes' => array(
                    'Twig_' => $pathToTwigLib,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
```

In `application.config.php` I am loading the modules `['Application','twig','ZfcTwig']`

Auto loading for twig is working (at least I can instantiate `Twig_Environment` in the bootstrap of ZfcTwig and other Controllers using `new`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Had the config cache enabled

The problem is exactly where I was wondering myself. The config needs to be loaded before the bootstrapping is done. This is however exactly what ZF2 does, unless, like me, you have the config cache enabled.

```
<?php
// config/applicaiton.config.php
return array(
  'module_listener_options' => array(
    // this prevents the call to getConfig on Modules
    // that implement the ConfigProviderInterface
    // default: false
    'config_cache_enabled' => true, 
  )
);
```